# How can I limit page cache/buffer size

Tags: ram, swap, rsync, 18.10

My problem is this:  My laptop has a relatively slow disk subsystem (amd I'm not going to buy a better one) and I backup my system using `rsync` which works well for me.  However, during the backup process, the files read are read into the buffer/cache of the system, which eventually triggers the swap system.

For example, running `cat Win10.qcow2 > /dev/null` a 60 GB file will result in

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2.2Gi       210Mi       170Mi        13Gi        12Gi
Swap:          30Gi        14Mi        30Gi
```

and if I write to a real device, like my USB backup drive, the swap starts being used, up to a couple of GB.  I do have `vm.swappiness = 0` in `/etc/sysctl`

By itself, this is not bad, but because of my slow disk system, the computer becomes less than sprightly in response to inputs.  Painfully slow, in fact.

What I would like to have is a method for limiting the amount of page buffer that the process can consume, leaving enough room to run smaller commands, such as opening a terminal.

What I have tried, is using `lxc`, which did not limit the system use of buffers, `docker` which I could not fully figure out yet, and I'm attempting to get `lxd` running, but I'll need some time to figure that one out.

---

There is a program [`nocache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/nocache.1.html) which I think works, but `rsync` then does not output progress indicators.

Comment: @Fabby Not exactly a duplicate..  My swap is larger than need be, and I like keeping it around - but I'd really like to limit the amount of page/buffer cache that `rsync` consumes.  There is a program [`nocache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/nocache.1.html) which I think works, but `rsync` then does not output progress indicators.

Comment: Read the answer in its entirety and don't stop reading when it says "If you've got a server, that's it".  The nifty trick comes last.

Comment: @Fabby I'm treating this like an XY problem and posted an answer to change `rsync` behavior rather than swapiness. With `--inplace` argument `rsync` will do block writes rather than buffering. If I did my homework properly that is :)

Comment: Close Vote retracted, Answer upvoted!  @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default when `rsync` updates your backup it creates a copy of the file and then moves it into place. To avoid this step you can have `rsync` write directly to your backup with the `--inplace` argument.

As per https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync:

> **--inplace**
>
> This option changes how rsync transfers a file when the file's data needs to be updated: instead of the default method of creating a
>   new copy of the file and moving it into place when it is complete,
>   rsync instead writes the updated data directly to the destination
>   file.
>
> This has several effects:
>
> (1) in-use binaries cannot be updated
>   (either the
>       OS will prevent this from happening, or binaries that attempt to swap-in their data will misbehave or crash),
>
> (2) the file's data will
>   be in an inconsistent state during the transfer,
>
> (3) a file's data may
>   be left in an inconsistent state after the transfer if the transfer is
>   interrupted or if an update fails,
>
> (4) a file that does not have write
>   permissions can not be updated, and
>
> (5) the efficiency of rsync's
>   delta-transfer algorithm may be reduced if some data in the
>   destination file is overwritten before it can be copied to a position
>   later in the file (one exception to this is if you combine this option
>   with --backup, since rsync is smart enough to use the backup file as
>   the basis file for the transfer).
>
> **WARNING:** you should not use this
>   option to update files that are being
>       accessed by others, so be careful when choosing to use this for a copy.
>
> This option is useful for transfer of large files with
>   block-based changes
>       or appended data, and also on systems that are disk bound, not network bound.
>
> The option implies `--partial` (since an interrupted
>   transfer does not delete
>       the file), but conflicts with `--partial-dir` and `--delay-updates`. Prior to `rsync 2.6.4` `--inplace` was also incompatible with
>   `--compare-des`t and `--link-dest`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I appreciate the education on the workings of `rsync`, and should read the man pages more fully.  It eases the issue some, although I still manage to have a large pile of ram consumed by the page cache while the process runs.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Glad there is some progress. I'm doing a little more reading that might be of interest but doesn't totally answer your problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/258321/how-can-i-reduce-resource-usage-when-copying-a-large-file and https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?301264-linux-using-all-RAM-for-file-transfer-cache-destroying-system-performance

Comment: Both of those are interesting, and ones that I had not seen before.  I did have some limited success using `nice` on the `rsync`, and wrapping the program in a cgroup, but looking forward to experimenting with `ionice` and `buffer`

Comment: Some testing with the links indicates that I am going to get relief with the `ionice` command and the `--bwlimit` rsync parameter.  My backup disk is a USB, possibly older, and apparently it is not up to the speed demands that my computer is capable of asking for.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Yes I suspected  the `ionice` and `--bwlimit` options when I read the links but could not spot definitive reference for you.

Comment: At any rate...  The system is at least responsive now while a backup is in process - it still 'feels' a bit sluggy, but more like a busy machine than a non-responsive one.